# Importar archivos .jar a proyecto en Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, librería, jar

Tengo dos archivos un llamado main.jar y otro que es file.java.

```
 \
    main.jar
    file.java
```

y quisiera saber como puedo importar el archivo file main.jar

```
 import carpeta.file; // Ejemplo
```

Comment: Que IDE estas usando?

Comment: Estoy usando Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usas Eclipse tienes dos opciones para importar tu archivo .jar como se indica en la respuesta de [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc)

---

1. Haz clic botón derecho en tu proyecto.
2. Selecciona `Build Path` y `Add External Archives`
3. Seleccionas tu .jar
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

1. Haz clic botón derecho en tu proyecto.
2. Selecciona `Build Path`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Haz clic en `Configure Build Path`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4. Clic en `Libraries`, y selecciona `Add External JARs`, selecciona el archivo .jar que necesites registrar en tu proyecto, selecciona `Apply` y `OK`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]